# Solve $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} = \mathrm{e}^{y-1} \sec y (1+t^2)$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = x\mathrm{e}^{x^2-\ln y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone help me differential equation
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
  \dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} &=& \mathrm{e}^{y-1} \sec y (1+t^2) \\
  \dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} &=& x\mathrm{e}^{x^2-\ln y^2}
\end{array}
$$
i am confuse
can anyone show  me how to simplify that both equation into its general equation $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} + p(x) = q(x)$. thank you

Comment: **Hints:** For the first, we reduce the RHS to $\dfrac{x e^{x^2}}{y^2}$ and the second is separable to , $\dfrac{dy}{e^{y-1} \sec y} = ( t^2 + 1) ~dt$.

Comment: For the first equation  how can i reduce it like that because it has ln?

Comment: I got first and second reversed, we have $x e^{x^2 - ln y^2} = x e^{x^2}e^{-ln y^2} = x \dfrac{e^{x^2}}{y^2}$. Clear?

Comment: Ok thank you.for the second equation what should i do with sec y

Comment: Well, it becomes a cosine and then just integrate both sides.

Comment: is $y=y(x,t)=$?

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$$\int y^2 dy =\int xe^{x^2} dx \left( \ast \right)$$
And
$$\int e^{1-y}\cos y dy=\int 1+t^2 dt \left( \ast\ast \right)$$

Solve the $\left( \ast\ast \right)$ by integration by parts, we got $$\int e^{1-y}\cos y dy=-e^{1-y}\cos y -\int e^{1-y}\sin y dy=e^{1-y}\sin y - e^{1-y}\cos y -\int e^{1-y}\cos y dy$$

Add $\int e^{1-y}\cos y dy$ to both side and divide by 2 got $\int e^{1-y}\cos y dy=\frac{1}{2}(e^{1-y}\sin y - e^{1-y}\cos y)+ C$

So for $\left( \ast\ast \right)$ we have $$\frac{1}{2}(e^{1-y}\sin y - e^{1-y}\cos y)+ C=t+\frac{1}{3}t^3$$

For $\left( \ast \right)$ we simply have $$\frac{1}{3}y^3 =\frac{e^{x^2}}{2}+D$$

And you can do the rest